# Change "tick" mark color in mat checkbox

Tags: angular-material

I want to change the tick mark color inside the mat check box. I customised the mat checkbox and made the background color as white. But the tick mark color isn't visible clearly. Is there any way to change the tick color? Any help is appreciated.

[image]

Comment: Hey @yaswanth, it would be better if you share some code here. Best way is present us some demo via stackblitz so that anyone can guide you.

Comment: Please share more information. Either a demo link with code or code snippet. Else how can we help.

Answer (score 0):

You can use css file and connect it to the code, this is an example of one of my codes, i guess thats all you need to know:

```css
input[type="checkbox"]{
    -webkit-appearance: initial;
    appearance: initial;
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    border: none;
    position: relative;
    background: black;
}
input[class="player1"]:checked:after {
    /* Heres your symbol replacement - this is a tick in Unicode. */
    content: "X";
    color: orange;
    /* The following positions my tick in the center,
     * but you could just overlay the entire box
     * with a full after element with a background if you want to */
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    -webkit-transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
    -moz-transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
    -ms-transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
    transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
    /*
     * If you want to fully change the check appearance, use the following:
     * content: " ";
     * width: 100%;
     * height: 100%;
     * background: blue;
     * top: 0;
     * left: 0;
     */
}
input[class="player2"]:checked:after {
    /* Heres your symbol replacement - this is a tick in Unicode. */
    content: "O";
    color: blueviolet;
    /* The following positions my tick in the center,
     * but you could just overlay the entire box
     * with a full after element with a background if you want to */
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    -webkit-transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
    -moz-transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
    -ms-transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
    transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
    /*
     * If you want to fully change the check appearance, use the following:
     * content: " ";
     * width: 100%;
     * height: 100%;
     * background: blue;
     * top: 0;
     * left: 0;
     */
}
```